# Unable to debug libc source on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c, debugging, ubuntu

I'm trying to debug `libc` on Ubuntu 14.04 but unable to do so using `gdb` as the library and the source are not matching correctly.

`gdb` is unable to place the break point correctly. As in, I'm able to step into a function and see the source code but the break point marker would be at some random place inside the function instead of being at the beginning.

When I proceed statement by statement using `next` on `gdb`, the marker would keep jumping up and down (Reason being the source file and debug library are not matching correctly.

My `glibc` version according to `ldd` is

```
ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

I've downloaded `libc` sources using the command:

`sudo apt-get source libc6`

The above would create the following files:

```
eglibc-2.19  
eglibc_2.19-0ubuntu6.6.debian.tar.xz  
eglibc_2.19-0ubuntu6.6.dsc  
eglibc_2.19.orig.tar.xz
```

In `gdb` I'm doing

`dir <path-to-libc-source>/nptl` (nptl because I'm stepping into `pthread_create`)

I've tried using both `eglibc-2.19` source as well as `eglibc_2.19.orig.tar.xz`.

I've also tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/debug`

But the above also doesn't help.

Can somebody who has successfully been able to debug `libc` code share his/her techniques as to how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the source code version and the library version are the same....

The root cause of the 'jumping' is due to the compiler optimization often changes the order of the executable code from the order in the source file.

This happens when the code is compiled with any of the optimization parameters.

Comment: But won't `gdb` be using the debug library. I've also tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to debug lib path, even that doesn't help

Comment: 'gdb' uses what ever you tell it to use.  Normally you tell it the path/name of an executable.   the source files must be visible to 'gdb' for it to display the related code while stepping through the execution of the code.   Note: the library (especially for system libraries) will have all the debug info removed (probably via something similar to the 'strip' command),   Between the optimization and the debug info stripping, there is very little chance of easily debugging a system library.

Comment: I agree. But the libraries in `/usr/lib/debug` do have their debug infos intact